# Correlation between two consecutive observed states in a simple Hidden Markov Model with Gaussian emission

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, hidden-markov-model

### Backgrounds

Suppose a Hidden Markov process with Gaussian emission and two possible latent states: $s \in \{0,1\}$.

I have a observed sequence $\mathcal{X} = \{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_T \}$, where $X_i$: $n$-length vector. By Gaussian HMM assumptions, we have

- **Stationary Markov transition**: $p(s_{t+1} =1 | s_t =0) = p_{01}, p(s_{t+1} =0 | s_t =1) = p_{10}$ for all $1\le t\le T-1$.
- **Conditional independence**: $p(\mathcal{X} | s_1,\cdots,s_T) = \prod_{i=1}^T p(X_i|s_i)$
- **Gaussian emission**: $\displaystyle p(X_i|s_i=0) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_0, \Sigma_0\right)$, $p(X_i|s_i=1) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_1, \Sigma_1\right)$

For simplicity, the equal covariance is assumed: $\Sigma_0 = \Sigma_1 = \Sigma$. Assume we know the transition probability matrix $\Lambda$

$$
\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix} p_{00} & p_{01} \\ p_{10} & p_{11} \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $p_{01} = p(s_{t+1} = 1 | s_t = 0) = 1 - p_{00}$ and $p_{10} = p(s_{t+1} = 0 | s_t = 1) = 1 - p_{11}$ for any $t$.

---

### Problem

I would like to find the correlation between temporally adjacent vectors $(X_t, X_{t+1})$, *i.e.* $\displaystyle r_{t, t+1} = \widetilde{X}_{t+1}^T\widetilde{X}_t$, where the unit vectors $\displaystyle \widetilde{X}_i \overset{\text{def}}{=} X_i^c {\big/} \Vert X_i^c \Vert$ with the mean-centered vector $X_i^c = X_i - \overline{X_i} \mathbb{1}$ and $\overline{X_i}$: mean(scalar) of $X_i$.

---

### Try

I first calculated $p([X_t // X_{t+1}])$, where $[X_t  // X_{t+1}]$: 1D-concatenated vector, hoping it to be a form that follows Gaussian.

$$
\begin{aligned}
p([X_t // X_{t+1}]) &= \sum_{s_t} \sum_{s_{t+1}} p(X_t, X_{t+1}, s_t, s_{t+1}) \\
&= \sum_{s_t} \sum_{s_{t+1}} p(X_{t+1} | s_{t+1}) p(s_{t+1}|s_t) p(X_t | s_t) p(s_t) \\
&= p(s_t = 0) p(X_t | s_t=0) p(X_{t+1} | s_{t+1} =0)\cdot p_{00}  \\
&+ p(s_t = 0) p(X_t | s_t=0) p(X_{t+1} | s_{t+1} =1)\cdot p_{01}  \\
&+ p(s_t = 1) p(X_t | s_t=1) p(X_{t+1} | s_{t+1} =0)\cdot p_{10}  \\
&+ p(s_t = 1) p(X_t | s_t=1) p(X_{t+1} | s_{t+1} =1)\cdot p_{11}  \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Probably I messed up right here, since it seems that for $2n$-length vector $x=x_{1:2n}$,

$$
p(X_t = x_{1:n} | s_t = k) p(X_{t+1} = x_{(n+1):2n} | s_{t+1}=l) \sim \mathcal{N} \left( [\mu_0 // \mu_1], \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\Sigma} & \mathbf{O} \\ \mathbf{O} & \mathbf{\Sigma} \end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

from the conditional independence of $X_t | s_t \perp X_{t+1} | s_{t+1}$ (Sorry for abusing the distribution notation). So the final form may have the covariance of the form as follows:

$$
cov([X_t // X_{t+1}]) = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{\ast} & \mathbf{O} \\ \mathbf{O} & \mathbf{\ast} \end{bmatrix} 
$$

for some $\ast$ as a function of $\mu_0, \mu_1, p_{01}, p_{10}$, and possibly $\Sigma$.  I cannot proceed from here.. any help will be appreciated.